# Open all grouped windows with Alt-tab

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I wondered if it is possible to open all grouped windows of one application at once with Ubuntu's (well, Unity's) alt-tab mechanic. What I mean is the following case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u559k.png (can't embed the image as a new account).

I have two documents open in the PDF viewer and arranged them side by side. Now I switch to another application (say Latex) to do something and want to switch back to the PDFs to look at them. The standard alt-tab only opens one of the two PDFs and I have to bring the other into focus manually, which is annoying (the same also happens when you click on the icon).

Seems straightforward but I haven't figured it you yet. Can you configure Unity to just open all windows of an application when clicking or alt-tabbing to it? In the meantime, I open both the documents in another workspace and switch between workspaces with Ctrl+Alt+Arrow key.

Answer (score 0):

On the italian keyboard, it's (left) ALT plus PIPE (the key left to number 1 (not num pad))